# What is the significance of "stone that the builder refused"?

Tags: the-boondocks

The opening theme to *the Boondocks* series starts with the line "I am the stone that the builder refused"- what is this referring to? Is it a biblical reference?

Comment: Looks like a biblical reference to psalms 118:22

Comment: @ToddWilcox- OK, so just what is that passage supposed to mean?

Comment: The last stone we'd think would be used as the cornerstone—the most prominent stone, with the connotation that without it the structure would fall—would be one that the builder had previously refused as unusable. The verse then is  a blessing: if a person is like the stone, and if by refused we mean is not fit for this world, then they (the subjects of the verse) will be blessed instead with a most prominent place in the world. It's like saying he's the 2nd coming of Jesus, and moreover someone you'd least expect to be.

Comment: Why is there a bounty on this?  Asked and answered, move on.

Comment: @JasonPSallinger I hoped a bounty might bring more attention and possibly a better answer to this!

Answer (score 7):

This is similar to a phrase from [Psalm 118:22](https://biblehub.com/psalms/118-22.htm). There are various translations, but all are similar:

> The stone the builders rejected has become the cornerstone.

The implication (as I understand the context) is that a once-reject has become crucial.